# Validation for arrays in ParamFetcher Symfony FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I need some validation for array attributes in my ParamFetcher params:

Example:

```
/**
* @RequestParam(name="client[name]", strict=true, requirements="...")
* @RequestParam(name="client[phone]", strict=true, requirements="...")
*/
public function createAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher) 
{
  //...
}
```

How I can do this? Maybe you have alternative ways to do this? Using `ParamFetcher` not necessary

Comment: I want to do the same thing, did you manage to find a solution using the ParamFetcher ?

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe have a look at the [OptionsResolver Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/options_resolver.html) of Symfony.

You could easily implements your own logic to "client" defining mandatory keys, default values, validations... and manage triggered errors to throw BadRequestException and return detailed errors.